# How do I add Biomes to a Procedurally Generated Terrain with Open Simplex Noise in Godot

Tags: game-development, godot, terrain, procedural-generation, gdscript

I have an Open Simplex Terrain generation in Godot system based on the one showed in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWeQ30h25Yg) video, and I was wondering the most simple way I could implement biomes like mesas, mountains, plains, etc. How would I alter the height different segments of the terrain while keeping them seamlessly connected, and also how would I change the intensity of the noise in these areas to make them flatter or higher?

Comment: I'm going to suggest looking at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com - Although I don't think there is something Godot specific, there is plenty on noise, biomes and terrain generation.

Comment: Alright thanks! I didn't know there was a separate site for game development help.